# How do I link a topic to a question?

Tags: support, asking-questions, link

I see many questions (e.g. [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328500/how-do-i-install-ebook-reader-problems-with-fbreader)) have other relevant questions linked to them. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *do it* yourself. The system read the tags and url in comments/questions/answers for relevance:

In this example, all questions share the [ebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ebook) with your question:

[image]

The linked question is because the answer includes a link to that question:

[image]

[image]

Also, it shows the questions that are back-linked to yours. Check this out. https://askubuntu.com/questions/linked/13758?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

These links are generated from actual links in the question, answer, or comments to either of these.

You can put a link on one side and the link will actually go in both directions.

As you can see, if you follow the linked question to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand) you see that there is quite a number of linked questions, even though it itself doesn't contain links to them.